# After setting state in react an infinite loop starts

Tags: reactjs, infinite-loop, use-state

I am having an issue where an infinite loop start after setting new state in my app.js. I think best is to take a look at the code:

```
const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState([]);
const markAsFavorite = (currentCharacter) => {
    setFavorites({ ...currentCharacter });
  };
return(
<SingleCharacter
    characters={characters}
    globalUser={globalUser}
    markAsFavorite={markAsFavorite}
/>
```

```
function SingleCharacter({ characters, globalUser, markAsFavorite }) {
  const { id } = useParams();
  let currentCharacter = characters[id - 1];

  const handleClick = (currentCharacter, globalUser) => {
    markAsFavorite(currentCharacter);
  };

  return (
<button
  className="logoutButton"
  onClick={() => {
  handleClick(currentCharacter);
  }}
  >
  Mark as favorite
  </button>)
```

As soon as I click the button the loop starts and I dont understand why... any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you use useEffect anywhere? Also, your  setFavorites({ ...currentCharacter }) is wrong. Set it as setFavorites([...favorites,  currentCharacter ])

Comment: I'm doubting that the problem is from `favorites`, could you share the code where you're using `favorites`, too?

Comment: I use a useEffect to fetch the data: 
const shouldFetch = useRef(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (shouldFetch.current) {
      shouldFetch.current = false;
      fetchData("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character");
    }
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async (url) => {
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const data = await res.json();
    setCharacters((characters) => {
      return [...characters, ...data.results];
    });
    // if (data.info && data.info.next) {
    //   fetchData(data.info.next);
    // }
  };

Comment: ATM favorites is not being used anywhere. First i wanted to avoid the loop before using it